# Distance from 2 Points on the same Plane

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

I have a Plane, the normal and 2 vectors, where $v1\cdot v2 = 0$ and $\cdot$ is the dot product, on the plane are known. I also have 1 point, which is considered the middle, and another point anywhere on the plane. For both points, the coordinates are known.
Now I need to know where the second point is in relation to the first when looking straight onto the plane. If I get the distance between the two I basically get a circle around the middle where the second Point lies on.
One idea I had was to just measure the distance, or get the circle, for 3 Points, and by doing so "triangulate" the target point. I don't know if that would work, and if we would have the power left over to do all that.

I'd appreciate any other ideas, or insight if my idea would theoretically work

Edit for clarification:
If looking straight onto the plane, I need to know how much the target point is moved to the right/left from the middle and how much it is moved to the top/bottom from the middle

Comment: Can you describe more clearly what you want to find out exactly?

Comment: @Tavish I edited the question

Comment: Left/right/top/bottom are relative, so you will not get a unique answer.

Comment: But the target point is always relative to the middle

Comment: Keep your eyes  directly above the middle point of the plane. Now, if you rotate your head/the plane, you will see that the other point moves in a circle, constantly changing its ‘leftness’ and ‘rightness’. The only thing that remains constant is the radius of that circle which you can compute.

Comment: You can use the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ to define “left/right” and “up/down” within the plane.

Comment: @amd and then what?

Comment: The do whatever you might do in the $x$-$y$ plane, but using those two vectors to define the coordinate system.

Comment: @amd I understand what you're saying, but rn I have no clue how to execute that, neither in code nor on a piece of paper. Could you post a small example as an answer maybe?